# Logarithmic commission?

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function, percentages

Let's say that I have a product which combines of two elements.
I want to set my profit margin based on each element's part. Together both elements sum up to $100$%
I would like to charge more commission for smaller part and less for bigger one.

I'm trying to find common exponent using log function in such way that it will sum to 100 + my commission.

For example

$$60+40 = 100 $$

$$60^{x}+40^{x}=115$$

That $15$% commission should be split based on logarithmic function, by applying more weight to smaller part $(40)$.

Also example with 4 parts:

$$40^{x}+40^{x}+15^{x}+5^{x}=120$$

$40$% and $40$% would have the smallest commission and $5$% the largest applied.

Can someone solve both examples for me please?

Comment: You can just ask WolframAlpha to solve it for you, e.g. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+60%5Ex+%2B+40%5Ex+%3D+115. However your formula will always end up charging more commission for the larger part; in fact if any part is less than 1% then you'll charge negative commission for it.

Comment: When you say, "more commission on the smaller part" do you mean more dollars or a higher percentage?

Comment: thanks, but I would like to learn to how to do it by hand as well :)

Comment: @saulspatz more dollars for smaller percentage

Comment: Your basic approach seems incorrect.  I don't see how raising the percentages to exponents will achieve your goal.  As Rahul has said, you'll always charge more commission on the higher-priced item.

Comment: That's why I thought Log function could help me with that since it's exponential

Comment: What if the commission is a fixed value plus a percentage?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to guess at a function, I suggest your try to translate your requirements into mathematical terms.  As I understand it, in your example, you want $$\begin{align}
60r_1+40r_2&=15\\
60r_1&<40r_2,\end{align}$$ where $r_1,r_2$ are the commission rates.

Obviously, if the commissions were equal, we would have $$\begin{align}
60r_1&=40r_2=7.5\\r_1&={7.5\over60}=.125\\r_2&={7.5\over40}=.1875\end{align}$$

If you really need the commission on the smaller part to be larger, just choose $r_1$ to be any convenient number less than $12.5\%$ and use the equation $60r_1+40r_2=15$ to determine $r_2.$

Answer (score 0):

what if I do like this

Products = 2

Commission = 115 or 0.85

$K= log((2*0.85))/log(2) = 0.765535$

Therefore

$0.60^.765535 = 0.676$

$0.40^.765535 = 0.496$

So technically I've applied bigger profit margin to lower part but total commission is now 117% not 15%